# React: How to I get a React component button to lose focus?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on a pagination button, the focus state stays in the browser after the page updates.  How to I tell that component to blur?

This is where I'm calling the component.

```
<Paginate onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)} text="Prev"/>
```

This is the component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Paginate extends Component {
  render() {
    const {text} = this.props;

    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>{text}</button>
    )
  }
}

export default Paginate;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use React `ref` API. When the button is mounted, you sent the reference to its DOM element locally and when you click, you call `blur` DOM API.

Check the example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtkhanas/af3eau1a/55/

Comment: You don't need the added complexity of `ref`, you already get a reference to the DOM element through the click event.
`onClick={e => e.target.blur()}`

Answer (score 19):

Adding to mrossman's comment in the accepted answer, what worked for me was `onClick={(e) => e.currentTarget.blur()}`.

Comment: Works in my case, verified with ant-design `Button`. Solution with `e.target.blur()` did _not_ work there.

Comment: this worked for me. passed e through a button's onClick function. then added the e.currentTarget.blur() within the onClick function's declaration.

Comment: To make this pass TypeScript with React's synthetic events, I had to use ```if (e.target instanceof HTMLElement) { e.target.blur(); }```.