# How can I submit input with ability to restore it's value with onBlur?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

I want to make simple functional Input component using hooks. I want it to submit its value on button click or Enter press.

```
const Input = ({ name, value, onSubmit }) => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState(value);
  //set input's value with props.value
  useEffect(() => {
    setInput(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        name={name}
        value={input}
        onBlur={() => setInput(value)}
        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      // show submit button if input has been changed
      {value !== input && (<input type='submit' onClick={onSubmit} />)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Restoring value with onBlur works fine. But when I want to submit input - I can't. OnBlur fires before onClick. Here, on SO I've found 2 suggestions:

1. Use onMouseDown, as it fires before onBlur. Ok, it works, but I want to keep my app keyboard friendly.
2. Add setTimeout to onBlur event. But it remembers old value, so even if I save changes, I can't see them right after re-render, which is not great at all.

I found solution. I added form with second onSubmit handler and changed onClick to onMouseDown in submit input:

```
const Input = ({ name, value, onSubmit }) => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState(value);
  //set input's value with props.value
  useEffect(() => {
    setInput(value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        name={name}
        value={input}
        onBlur={() => setInput(value)}
        onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      // show submit button if input has been changed
      {value !== input && (
        <input type='submit' onMouseDown={onSubmit} />)
      }
    </form>
  );
}
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lu4ezar/mkq0vtLg/30/).

There's one problem: input still has focus after submitting with Enter button. Is there a better way and, if no, how can I call onBlur from onSubmit function?

Comment: `input still has focus after submitting with Enter` - how is that a problem?

Comment: For example, in case I'd want to apply additional styling to it.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044463/react-how-to-i-get-a-react-component-button-to-lose-focus (but answer is about classes instead of https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: @Aprillion good one, I think I'm gonna use this. Thank you!